# Nissan Crank bolt: reverse thread?

Tags: nissan, stuck-bolt, crankshaft-pulley

Engine HR12DE
Nissan Micra K13 2011

Hello, I’ve been trying to remove the crank pulley bolt and it won’t come off. I also tried blocking it with a handle bar and cranking the engine, the trick didn’t work.
I’m starting to wonder if it is a reverse thread bolt? How can I know?

Thanks a lot

Pictures: pulley bolt and maintenance manual [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All Japanese cars using a clockwise thread bolt.

Meaning: You need to counterclockwise to loosen it.

- Use WD40 or lubricant fluid like WD40.
- Spray it around the bolt.
- Let it sink or wait 15minutes.
- And use an impact driver to loosen it up. Or hammering your wrench :D

Using blocking technic and cranking it, it just does more harm than good, you could bend the body or even the chassis or splitting the tools and flew away to your head.

The bolt could be sticky because of dry and rust. WD40 helps.

if it doesn't open, there is one last resort:

- Burn it :) I mean heating the outer part of the bolt or the bolt itself can makes difference. (PS: you don't need to burn it if the area full of plastic or there is oil in it)

Comment: A true penetrating oil like PB Blaster or Kroil is more effective than WD-40. Also heat is a good option but be careful, the harmonic balancer has a rubber element so it would be easy to torch it and ruin it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try again and follow your recommendations.

Comment: @masospaghetti I understand, but because I live in Indonesia which is only available like WD40 for the foreign brands and another just local (rexco, chromax, etc which is not everyone knows) so I suggest only the familiar brand. Well anyone can look up the best penetrating fluid.

Comment: @Florent more spray and wait longer works too. because in the very tight bolt, the fluid will be difficult to penetrate and needs more time to fully penetrate the bolt.

Comment: Hello all, I was able to borrow an impact wrench and I solved my problem. I’ll now finish tue job (timing adjustment) Thank you for your help, much appreciated.